# What is the recommended way of overriding version of a dependency from parent pom?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, bouncycastle

I want to override the bouncy castle version from the parent POM. I know we can add the dependency explicitly like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.69</version>
</dependency>
```

But this is not the recommended way, the recommended way is adding the version in the properties part of the POM, but I can't seem to find the name of the version property for Bouncy castle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is up to you to create and name such property.

```
<properties>
    <bouncycastle.version>1.69</bouncycastle.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Refer to the reference documentation of Maven POM: [Properties](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties)

Comment: I do not know why this correct answer was ignored while it was written 5 mins before the accepted answer and the accepted answer is not different from it.

Comment: Maybe a link in another answer was more helpful. Who knows, #life. Thanks for the support, though.

Answer (score 1):

> but I can't seem to find the name of the version property for Bouncy castle.

because it's custom, you need to create it.

You could define a custom property under  and refer to it from your dependency.
The preferred approach is to place the property in the parent pom.

```
<properties>
    <bouncycastle.version>1.69</bouncycastle.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There are some more ways you can check here to [override](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot) verison